# jquery find returning only one element (in Meteor)

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I have the following links that when clicked on should show fancyboxes--using the jquery plugin here: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

```
<div class="boxes">
    <a href="/signup.html" class="btn popup-link fancybox.ajax">Sign Up</a>
    <a href="/signin.html" class="btn popup-link fancybox.ajax">Sign In</a>
   </div>
```

The problem i'm having is that the fancybox works only for the first link.
In Meteor, I have:

```
Template.mytemplate.rendered = function () {

        console.log($(this.find('a.popup-link')));
        $(this.find('a.popup-link')).fancybox({
            padding: 18,
            openMethod: 'changeIn',
            closeBtn   : false,
            beforeShow: function() {
                $('input:checkbox').ezMark();
                $('select').selectbox();

                $('.trigger-ajax').on('click', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault()
                    $('.fancybox-wrap').animate({ 'left': '-100%'}, 400, function() {
                        $(this).parent().find('.popup-link').trigger('click');
                    })
                })
            }
        });

}
```

When i click on the first link my fancybox loads as expected but when i click on the second nothing happens.

Via the console.log its also clear that the find is returning only the first element ...hence the problem.

Note it doesn't work if i just do `('a.popup-link')` without the `find`.

What's going on? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `this.findAll('a.popup-link')` instead of `this.find('a.popup-link')` if you were trying to use the Meteor template method (not the jQuery *find()* method).

However, *findAll()* returns an array of DOM elements that I'm not sure if $() will accept as a parameter. If it doesn't though, you can just loop through the elements of the array.

Comment: Thanks findAll worked for me within $(). I wasn't sure what findAll was as I thought i was calling the jquery "find" method

Answer (score 2):

I think you're using a different `find` method. Use:

```
$(this).find('a.popup-link').fancybox({
```

I'm not sure how `this.find('a.popup-link')` was ever working, but I guess it depends on what `this` and `find` were/did. To use the jQuery method `find`, you need a jQuery object. That's what `$(this)` does. From there, you can find "a.popup-link" descendants with `find`.

Comment: @SetSailMedia Well, I'm not sure I'd call it broken. It was clearly working (the same jQuery code in the `console.log` and the selector part). But it all depends on what `this` is. For all we know, it's `window` (or an object), and there could be a `find` method defined.

Comment: i think "this" was referring to a meteor object in this case and "find" was referring to a meteor specific thing....hence the weird behavior. Thanks for this response!

Comment: @algorithmicCoder Ahh okay, never used meteor before, just noticed that weird syntax.