# What Is The Meteor Way To Bind jQuery to the DOM?

Tags: jquery, binding, meteor

I have a contact form with the ID contactForm in an HTML file (ContactForm.html). In the matching ContactForm.js file I have attempted to bind, via jQuery, a JavaScript validation tool like this:

```
Template.ContactForm.rendered = function () {
    $("#contactForm").validationEngine();
}
```

My problem is that the binding does not happen and the validationEngine is not triggered.

What is the proper Meteor way to bind to DOM objects with jQuery?

Bob

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `$( this.find("#contactForm") ).validationEngine();`

`this` inside of rendered is described at http://docs.meteor.com and there is another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15885287/728291) with more example code.  There is further discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17507431/728291) about reactivity or focus on the DOM element sometimes effecting the binding so maybe you are running into that.

Comment: If there's only one `#contactForm` element in the app, the code will be functionally identical.

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding `#contactForm` element in the template with a `{{#constant}}` block. Many UI plugins are not prepared to work with reactivity. `{{#constant}}` turns it off so that the additional functionality can be used.

Comment: {{#constant}} is a good idea and I will try that. My concern is that it's not a general solution and may not work in other circumstances where the DOM element I want to bind a jQuery function to  is, and needs to be, reactive. Will Meteor require its own special set of jQuery plugins?

Answer (score 0):

I know you are using validation engine now, BUT there is a smart package on Atmosphere called Mesosphere that is made to work specifically with Meteor, has rules, formats, transforms and aggregations and allows you to validate across client AND server..

Full Disclosure: I created Mesosphere.

That said there are a couple minor bugs that have been patched and pushed to github that are not in Atmosphere yet so using:

```
"Mesosphere": {
    "git": "https://github.com/copleykj/Mesosphere"
}
```

in your smart.json will allow you to use the bug fixes until the next release to Atmosphere.

Comment: I saw your package and am interested. I may end up switching to it even if I get this specific problem solved.